# SharePoint API postman collections?

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, postman

Whether you are using SharePoint on-prem or SharePoint online, there are many times when you want to do rest api calls to sharepoint to get certain tasks done.

I use Postman to store common api calls.

Does anyone know of any SharePoint postman collections with many of the REST api calls?

I would like to not have to reinvent the wheel here.

For example creating a sub-site, creating a site collection, deleting a sub-site, deleting a site collection, sharing a document to a user, etc.